# use array outside the parent function

Tags: javascript

with this function triggered as a callback

```
 var testing  = []; 
 var vid;

function showMyVideos(data){

        var feed = data.feed; //object "feed"
        var entries = feed.entry || [];   //array "entry"
        var html = ['<ul>'];
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
            entry = entries[i];
            playCount = entry.yt$statistics.viewCount.valueOf() + ' views';
            title = entry.title.$t;

            vid = (getVideoId(entry.link[0].href));
            testing[i] = vid;
            lnk = '<a href = \'' + entry.link[0].href + '\'>link</a>';
            html.push('<li>', title, ', ', playCount, ', ', vid, ', ', lnk, '</li>');

        }
        html.push('</ul>');
        $('#videoResultsDiv').html(html.join(''));


     }
```

---

I want to use the "testing" array on other functions, how will I do that?.. I'm frustrated  now, sorry I'm just starting to appreciate JavaScript. I want to perfectly access the array data like when I'm doing on
    console.log(testing)
inside the function..

Comment: Since "testing" is in the global scope, you should be able to use it anywhere already.

Comment: You can do this by calling it in the other function and make sure that there is no params or vars with the same name

Comment: why is it sometimes when I'm getting empty array, like this symbol on console (disregard quotes) -->    "[]"     

note: I'm pulling data from youtube API

additional question,
http://screencast.com/t/RKMudJFS9lE7

Answer (score 0):

"testing" is in the global scope and it should be accesible anywhere as long as there isn't another variable in another scope with the same name overriding the global "testing".

If the values aren't accesible in the place you are trying it, it could be because that function is getting executed before the callback loads the values in "testing".

Comment: exactly.. this was the main reason on my problem.. thanks guys for fast feedbacks. I'm getting to love this community :)

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned `testing` is global scope, so you can use it anywhere. So it's important that you have the correct execution order for the functions using `testing`.

Some might frown on using global scope in javascript but there are ways to mitigate issues.

Generally when I have to implement global scope vars, I will create a method along the lines of 'clear_session' or 'reset_globals'.

In your case a function like that would look like this:

```
function reset_globals(){
   testing  = []; 
   vid;
}
```

This is useful because then you know that after you call `reset_globals()` that your variables are going to be empty.